# How to Fade in and out Horizontally from Left to Right in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, fadein, fadeout, fading

I want to Animate Text in such a way that it fades in and out Horizontally from Left to Right.
But as I'm absolute beginner in Flutter I am not able to do this in Flutter.
I did search as how to achieve this in Flutter but I didn't find the solution.
Please help me how can I do this in Flutter!
[Image link of desired Fading Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yr4N.gif)